# Checkbox "checked" value conflict with session and DB values PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session, checkbox

I've been trying for a few days to figure this out but can't get it to work out correctly as I run through testing the scenarios. Basically, this is on an edit form, so it's pulling the stored value from the database. I have it save as either "1" or "0", 1 being checked. It's also a single checkbox, not an array.

I'm trying to figure out how to make the session correctly store the choice of my checkbox so that if there's an error on the page, etc, it shows my session value correctly, but what happens is that the DB value usually ends up trumping that.

So how can I initially first display the DB value, but then display the session value if changed?

Here's what I've been playing with.

```
if(isset($_SESSION["include_due_date"])) {                      
        $include_due_date = 'checked="checked"';                
} else {            
    if((!isset($_SESSION["include_due_date"])) && $resInvoice[0]["include_due_date"]  == 1 ) {
            $include_due_date = 'checked="checked"';
    } elseif((isset($_SESSION["include_due_date"])) && $resInvoice[0]["include_due_date"]  == 0 ) {
            $include_due_date = 'checked="checked"';
    } elseif((!isset($_SESSION["include_due_date"])) && $resInvoice[0]["include_due_date"]  == 0 ) {
            $include_due_date = '';
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

ADDITIONAL METHOD:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" <?php echo (isset($_SESSION['include_due_date'])?' checked="checked"' : (!isset($_SESSION['include_due_date'])) && $resInvoice[0]['include_due_date']  == 1?' checked="checked"' : ''); ?> name="include_due_date" id="include_due_date" />
```

Comment: Checking the box will not change the value in the session until you submit the form and the page reloads. At first load the db value will always take precedence. A js solution maybe right for your problem.

Comment: If you don't have any `form input` then the `database value` is the one to show. If you have `input from a form` _then that is the input to use!_. i.e. if the checkbox is set in $_POST then set the database to true. If the checkbox _is NOT in $_POST_ then set the `database value` to false.

Answer (score 0):

> So how can I initially first display the DB value, but then display
>   the session value if changed?

```
session_start(); // (Be sure to use session_start)
// If the include_due_date was set by the session
if(isset($_SESSION["include_due_date"])) {  
    // Set the value of $checked to the value of the session variable
    // In this way, the value of the session variable takes precedence over that in the database
    $checked = ($_SESSION["include_due_date"] === true);                
} else {            
    // The session variable wasn't set, so use the value from the database to set both the checked value and the session variable.  
    // The next request will use the value from the session variable
    if($resInvoice[0]["include_due_date"] == 1 ) {
        $_SESSION["include_due_date"] = $checked = true;
    } else {
        $_SESSION["include_due_date"] = $checked = false;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if ($checked) echo 'checked="checked"; ?> name="include_due_date" id="include_due_date" />
```

Comment: Hmm, I can already pull the db value and display that.  My problem is that I need it to correctly display the checkbox with the session, but when the checkbox is unchecked and I submit the form, and then return to it due to an intentional testing error, it will not display the checkbox as unchecked, but rather checked from the db value.  See my alternate method that I tried too.

Comment: We are missing code to store the database and to update the session. Could the error be there? you should display it.